# Python page count down print (len(elem_href1-(number)))

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

How do I create a page count down for python for each page it navigates to.  I have included my attempts below.  How do I get desired result?

I am using (len(elem_href1) so I can try and create page count down so easily informed of where my script is progressing. Trying to do that - a value each loop.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#questions .question-hyperlink")
elem_href1 = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]
print(elem_href1)
print (len(elem_href1))
shuffle(elem_href1)
for link in elem_href1:#(2)
    driver.get(link)
    print(len(link))
    import numbers

    #number = number -= 1
    #print (len(elem_href1-(number)))



print (len(elem_href1)) gives total number of pages to navigate to.


print(len(link)) gives random number due to shuffle.
```

Current output:

```
15
83
101
112
72
107
106
84
```

Desired:

```
50 #When at page 50
49 #when at page 49..
48 #when at page 48..
42 #Counting down...
..
```

Maybe then:

```
    number = number -= 1
    print (len(elem_href1-(number)))
#SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Or:

```
count = len(elem_href1)
def countdownList(l):  # 3. prints number of files left to process
    global count
    count = count - 1
    print(count, " pages left to go.")
    if count == 0:
```

Output:

```
    15
   43
```

Any ideas how this might be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you looking for the len of the strings and sorting it out, try this.

```
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions')
elements = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in 
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#questions .question-hyperlink")]
print(len(elements))

numbers = sorted([len(e) for e in elements], reverse=True)
print(numbers)
```

**update**

```
def page_counter():
  for x in range(1000):
      yield x

count = page_counter()

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions')
elements = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in 
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#questions .question-hyperlink")]
print(len(elements)) 

links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in elements)

for key, value in links.items():
   driver.get(value)
   print(f'At Page: {key}')
```

**2nd update**

```
import operator

links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in elements)
desc_links = sorted(links.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for link in desc_links:
    driver.get(link[1])
    print(f'At Page: {link[0]}')
```

Comment: The reason I use  print (len(elem_href1) is so I can try and create page count down so easily informed of where my script is progressing.  Trying to do that - a value each loop. This gives a list.

Comment: my bad i did not understand it properly, I've updated the code and see if it helps you

Comment: This counts up rather than down :).  The reason I want down is so I can know how long script has to go.

Comment: what about now? I've sorted the dict.

Comment: Just what I needed.  Cheers.

Comment: On further testing, the links are not shuffled and it does not work for all pages.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710581/how-to-create-page-counter-with-shuffled-links  .  Still, quite useful for SO with no shuffle.

Comment: I've responded to your question from the link, see if that will help

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems that `len(link)` has nothing related to shuffle. It looks like it just prints length of the string of current link.
If you want to see a number of 'pages left to go' you can just do:

```
for i, e in enumerate(elem_href1):
    print(len(elem_href1) - i)
```

or

```
left_to_go = len(elem_href1)

print(left_to_go)

for e in elem_href1:
    left_to_go -= 1
    print(left_to_go)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do a count down though for each page.  So rather than 15, 14, 13.  You get 15 when 15 pages to go. 14 for 14 pages?