# How to create Page counter with shuffled links

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I  am wanting to create page count down for shuffled links so easily informed of where my script is actually progressing.

I try:

```
def page_counter():
  for x in range(1000):
      yield x

count = page_counter()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.betstar.com.au/sports/soccer/')
elements = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".market-group a")]
 shuffle(elements)
print(len(elements))

import operator

links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in elements)
desc_links = sorted(links.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for link in desc_links:
    driver.get(link[1])
    print(f'At Page: {link[0]}')
```

Current Output (random numbers):

```
   64
    At Page: 44
    At Page: 24
    At Page: 34
    At Page: 46
    At Page: 42
    At Page: 10
```

The above is not really useful to know how it is progressing.
Change to:

```
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions')
```

Change to:

```
 driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#questions .question-hyperlink")]
```

I get(which is also my DESIRED output as it counts down)

```
15
At Page: 15  #When at page 15
At Page: 14   #When at page 15
At Page: 13  #When at page 15
At Page: 12
At Page: 11
At Page: 10
At Page: 9
```

How do I create a page counter with shuffled links?

I have also tried to get this working:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


driver.get('https://www.betstar.com.au/sports/soccer/')
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".market-group a")
elem_href1 = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]
print(elem_href1)
print (len(elem_href1))
shuffle(elem_href1)
for link in elem_href1:#(2)
    driver.get(link)
    print(len(link))
    import numbers

    #number = number -= 1
    #print (len(elem_href1-(number)))



print (len(elem_href1)) gives total number of pages to navigate to.


print(len(link)) gives random number due to shuffle.
```

Not supported, though the links are shuffled though no way of knowing how script is progressing

How to create page counter so that it displays desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

**Replace**

```
links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in elements)
desc_links = sorted(links.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

for link in desc_links:
    driver.get(link[1])
    print(f'At Page: {link[0]}')
```

**With**

```
import collections
links = dict((next(count) + 1, e) for e in elements)

desc_links = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(links.items(), reverse=True))

for key, value in desc_links.items():
    driver.get(value)
    print('At Page: ' + str(key))
```

Comment: Any idea how I'd go about this when dealing with clicking a webpage as no href?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901397/page-counter-for-css-elements?noredirect=1#comment82769741_47901397

Comment: Can you elaborate in detail? If I'm not wrong, you are navigating soccer section, and trying to click listings under main lists. If my understanding is correct, what is the error you are getting. I'm sorry, I'm not able to piece together the issue from the question

Comment: I've included my exact error.  I've also specified which area i believe to be causing exact issue.  You are correct, I am trying to navigate the soccer selection but have a page counter for this.  In example above works great for href but having trouble when no href

Comment: I think: elements = [x.get_text() for x or other variations I have tried is not right which is causing problems.